# How to count number by group of three (pattern)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, counter

I've been solving this problem for 2 hours now and can't seem to figure out how to count by the pattern.

Pattern:

```
1-1-1
1-1-2
1-2-1
1-2-2
2-1-1
2-1-2
2-2-1
2-2-2
```

And so on...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count? The total number of possible groups? So the count in the example above would be 8.

Comment: A loop of three numbers with the pattern like above. For example, given input of 5, the pattern will continue up to ... 4-4-4, 4-4-5, 4-5-4, 4-5-5, 5-4-4, 5-4-5, 5-5-4, 5-5-5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I think is to use that pattern as a two demonsional array, make a function that just loops over each number and just add the desired number, note that the pattern then should start with 0, here is a live example

```js
let myPattern = [
  [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1],
  [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]
];

function generateGroupPattern(pattern, n) {
  return pattern.map(p => p.map(sp => sp + n - 1));
}

console.log(generateGroupPattern(myPattern, 1).join("\n"));
console.log(generateGroupPattern(myPattern, 5).join("\n"));
console.log(generateGroupPattern(myPattern, 6).join("\n"));

// use a loop for example
for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(generateGroupPattern(myPattern, i).join("\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never thought of that. I've been trying to clock each index of the group of numbers individually using loops.  Big help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, happy coding!